# Получение таблицы SQL: ошибка "types ... must be identical"

Tags: delphi, sql

```
var
utf8FileName: UTF8string;
IResult :Integer;
SqlRes  :TSQLiteResult;
rCount  :Pansichar;
cCount  :Pansichar;
errormsg:Pansichar;
begin
...
SQLite3_GetTable(db,'SELECT * FROM moz_logins',SqlRes,rCount,cCount,errormsg);
```

Ошибка типа:

> `[DCC Error] uFirefox.pas(121): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical`

Но, судя по коду, все переменные объявлены, может тип переменных не тот? Может не PansiChar, а dword?

Курсор встал после rCount.

Comment: > Может не PansiChar а dword?  
![ыфв][1]  
Вам виднее)


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/4Gzvr.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical - говорит о несоответствии типов

посмотрите типы данных, которые нужно передать в процедуру, и сравните с тем, что вы передаете - вот где собака зарыта

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл в чём была причина=)